# You cannot create alerts for lists for which users can only read their own items.

Tags: 2013, custom-list, alert

I am having a list in SP2013,when i am clicking on the list alerts i am getting the error like "You cannot create alerts for lists for which users can only read their own items".
I am having Full Control permissions,can any one help on this how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have unique permission set on the List i.e user can see the items which they added.

Workaround:

Method # 1:

- Grant everybody in the list with read permission.

Method 2:

- Create your own custom Workflow, which will send email on item adding / update item.
- Create an event recievre for it.

Method 3:

- Try 3rd party tool i.e [harePoint Alerts from bamboo](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/c-8-alerts.aspx)

also check this http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/05/read-only-users-unable-to-create-alerts.html